# SumLineLengths in QGIS 3.2 not working?

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, linestring, length, count

I'm trying to use the Vector > Analysis Tools > Sum Line Lengths in QGIS version 3.2.3-Bonn.  I'm inputting a ploygon (Multi Polygon) and a Lines (MultiLineString) shape files.  I'm hoping to get the count and length of lines in each square of the polygon grid.  The error I'm getting is;

> Algorithm 'Sum line lengths' starting… Input parameters: {
>   'COUNT_FIELD' : 'COUNT', 'LEN_FIELD' : 'LENGTH', 'LINES' : 'X:/SAERI
>   Contracts/CFL/Toothfish ms/Map/layers/LL_lines.shp', 'OUTPUT' :
>   'memory:', 'POLYGONS' :
>   'MultiPolygon?crs=EPSG:4326&field=fid:double(20)&field=left:double(23,15)&field=top:double(23,15)&field=right:double(23,15)&field=bottom:double(23,15)&field=id:long(10)&uid={411cf258-ceb3-4878-810c-8c14545a6a79}'
>   }
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\SumLines.py",
>   line 119, in processAlgorithm
>   QgsFeatureRequest().setSubsetOfAttributes([]).setDestinationCrs(poly_source.sourceCrs(),
>   context.transformContext())), feedback) Exception: unknown
>
> Execution failed after 0.02 seconds

Both layers are in the same projection (WGS84) and I've also tried UTM21S but get the same error.

Or is this a bug?

Or something wrong with my installation?